# clickToggle or toggle jquery functions

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate, toggle

Hi everyone i created a small code to animate a box (show,hide) and something wrong with my code i can't find the right solution... if i create a simple click function it works but i won't create two different clicks so I'm using toggle function.

(Im using query transit to scale to 0 the box)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#mobile_bar").clickToggle(function() {   
    $("#navigation_box").fadeIn(500);
},
function() {
    $("#navigation_box").transition({ scale: 0, delay: 500 });
}); });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mobile_bar").click(function () {
        var $navBox = $("#navigation_box").clearQueue();
        if (!$(this).data('toggle')) {
            $navBox.fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $navBox.transition({
                scale: 0,
                delay: 500
            });
        }
        $(this).data('toggle', !$(this).data('toggle'));
    });
});
```

PS: not sure `transition` plugin uses the `fx` queue or not?!

Comment: A. Wolf : This works well but not as toggle :/ Need to find a way to make it with toggle or something

Comment: But are you talking about http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ or http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ ???

Comment: First one, now the script runs so the box show and disappears but after then i can't click on the mobile_bar nothing happens. thats why i want to make it work like api.toggle

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle which replicate your issue because this shouldn't happen. Anyway, any error in console? BTW, you said the first one but looks like you are talking about second one, so this is really confusing...

Comment: Sorry these toggle things are not my favorite part of the web :)
No error in console and the code is fine too and i see you added toggle in the bottom of the script this part is not working somehow

Comment: @psdDesigner As you can see, click as toggle method works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/MgR9E/  So your issue is somewhere else. Anyway, again you should `Provide a jsFiddle which replicate your issue `

Comment: I tested on jsFiddle and there everything works just as i want. Hmm i think ill check my full code maybe a missed something. 

Thank you for your help Wolf:)